# How to change object key color in vscode, for React app?

Tags: json, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[This link shows how to edit json object keys](https://github.com/lokesh-coder/aditi/blob/master/themes/aditi-dark-color-theme.json), but the problem is it doesn't work in my React app I have. I made it using `create-react-app`. The following will change the color of json objects:

```
{
      "name": "JSON Key - Level 0",
      "scope": [
        "source.json meta.structure.dictionary.json support.type.property-name.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#b379a1"
      }
    }
}
```

This works for for the settings.json file, but not for the React app.

```
function mapAppStateToProps(appState) {
    return {
        currentUser: appState.user.currentUser
    }
}
```

currentUser key doesn't change even though the settings.json file changes all the json key colors. I've even added all the code from the link above to style 8 layers of json keys, to no avail. How can I style json keys in a React app in vscode?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
{
   "scope": "meta.object-literal.key",
   "settings": {
       "foreground": "#FF0000"
   }
}
```